# Alternative to a columns of checkboxes in a table

Tags: usability, design-patterns, checkboxes, categorization

Here's the scenario:
A Person has a bunch of Accounts. Accounts may (or may not) have Services attached to it depending on the type of Account. Currently there are two types of Service (indicated by Columns 1 & 2 in the pic below) but the types of Services **will** grow in the future (maybe up to 4-6 sort of range)

Some Account types qualify for some Services but not others, etc.

The big system constraint is that all of the Services and Accounts for the Person must be submitted together.

Here is the design proposed by the client:

[image]

To me, the suggested designs weakness seems to be the problem of growing Services.

I'm interested in alternatives.

This question provided some interesting ideas but didn't quite fit my use case:

[Best UI pattern for letting a user assign items to groups](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/30049/best-ui-pattern-for-letting-a-user-assign-items-to-groups/30069#30069)

Comment: So reversing the original design so that there is a list of Accounts and letting them select from a list of services will not work?

Answer (score 3):

What your client proposes works, I would change the order though: Accounts first then services.

It is understandable, there is no confusion, you can add as many services as you want.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPbOpI.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Maybe what is confusing is the fact that the services names are numbers so I imagine there is some logic between those services.

If the administrator knows the name of the services she wants to add. And only then, you can use that type of interface :

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUoyr9.png)</sup>

If it is more like all the services are added except one, adapt the interface and add all the available services by default an let the user discard those that are not needed.