# UI pattern: assign to list + details

Tags: web-app, design-patterns

assigning items to a list is well-known UI pattern and is already discussed at [ux.se](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/30049/best-ui-pattern-for-letting-a-user-assign-items-to-groups).

Example:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1VGdt.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

The case I've stumbled on a few times recently is: Assigning items to a list and display details for the items. The UI pattern is only used for desktop web applications as mobile has different requirements.

I can imagine two approaches:

**1. One shared detail view for both lists**

Wouldn't the user be confused that one area is used for two different areas?

Side note: The current approach is using one list with checkboxes and provide a filter to show the selected checkboxes only. I like the idea, but it's quite uncommon and it can't handle the 2nd approach:

**2. Details for each list** - comparison of detailed information possible

Requirement is that I have the possibility to have all 4 views on the same page.

I'm wondering if anyone come up with a proper solution?

How it could look like:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZWCTE.png)</sup>

Comment: I've hated this UI element for years. Takes up too much horizontal space, imo. I'd love to see alternatives.

Comment: The details list only presents info on items?

Comment: I've updated the question with a mock what elements are expected (not the interaction)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to ThaSaleni, you could separate the list into two parts.
"Oscar Awards" at the top and "Oscar Nominees" below that, this way it would be easier to find what the awarded movies are.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's my suggestion:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftSLlI.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Basically you have a list with everything and an inline label to show the movies which actually got the awards.

Comment: Hi thanks, I like the concept. The major use case is to see the awarded Oscars, who is really interested in the nominated ones? ;)

Comment: the idea is this is the whole oscar nominees list, highlighting the actual winners, but you could tweak as you like

Comment: the problem in my scenario is that their are 1000 nominations and only 5 awards. The user would really lose the overview of the important entries.

Comment: I get it, :) have you found another way to do it yet|?

Comment: No, nothing satisfying so far.

Comment: whats the whole use case of this scenario? what will the user be looking for and willing to achieve?

Comment: Depends, we need those patterns in various scenarios. One might be to select from a list of people a few which will work on a task. To choose who will be assigned or unassigned the details need to be checked (> 20 attributes)

Comment: could a table with filters work better?

Comment: In some use cases, yes. We are going for that when possible. But in some use cases comparison of assigned and not-assigned items are required.