# Best UI pattern to allow the user to assign 1 level nested items to two groups

Tags: gui-design, checkboxes, drag-n-drop

My issue is something similar to this one - [Best UI pattern for letting a user assign items to groups](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/30049/best-ui-pattern-for-letting-a-user-assign-items-to-groups)

I am looking for a good UI design for mapping items between 2 groups (only one-to-one mapping). These items can be under a parent or by itself.
I thought of drag-and-drop/ having checkboxes (or switch like) to turn on for any one group.

Items       Group 1 Group 2

Item A
  Item A1   *checkbox checkbox*

Item B      *checkbox checkbox*

Comment: Is the mapping unique? In the sense one group item can be uniquely grouped with a different item from the other group but not assignable to another item?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a [transfer list](https://material-ui.com/components/transfer-list/) could be what you're looking for.

> A transfer list (or "shuttle") enables the user to move one or more list items between lists.

[image: Transfer list_Material UI]

(Note: both link and screenshot refer to Material UI. There might be other visualizations or implementation that might suit your needs better. Nonetheless, you should get the idea)

Answer (score 0):

On the simplest level you could just try a dropdown which lets you select the item on the right - might not be fancy though.

On a little interactive method you could use something like s chord diagram where after a drag amd select you display the relationship.