# How would you build a popup form for creating a group of users?

Tags: forms, lists, popup, user-feedback, grouped-list

For now I came out with this design/approach:
[image]

2 lists, one near another, with checkboxes on the users selection side and crosses(for quick removal) on the new building group.

I tried to search elsewhere but couldn't find other approaches, would you find it as a good UX?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best UI for multi-selecting from a list?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3418/what-is-the-best-ui-for-multi-selecting-from-a-list)

Comment: Related [question/answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/28995/115107)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked up those questions in the comments and it gave me some good overview on approaches and reasons and ideas, in the end I think I will stick with this former experience with a little tweak(bold font for the checked users) given that I want the same UX also for the smartphone users, like this:
[image]